# Invalid casing in Windows drive letter with Yarn and NextJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, windows, next.js, yarnpkg

I setup a new project using Yarn and NextJS on my **Windows** machine today. Upon start-up, I get an error that the casing is "invalid" for my project directory. Specifically, I am seeing the following errors:

- `Invalid casing detected for project dir, received c:\super-amazing-project actual path C:\super-amazing-project`
- `There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.`

The kicker is that in the error message the two paths are identical **except for the drive letter**.

How do I fix this?

### Versions

- Yarn version 1.22.17
- NextJS version 12.1.5

### Console output

```
c:\super-amazing-project>yarn dev
yarn run v1.22.17
$ next dev
warn  - Invalid casing detected for project dir, received c:\super-amazing-project actual path C:\super-amazing-project, see more info here https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-project-dir-casing
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000

./node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* C:\super-amazing-project\node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    C:\super-amazing-project\node_modules\react\index.js
* c:\super-amazing-project\node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    c:\super-amazing-project\node_modules\react\index.js
```

### `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "super-amazing-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^1.8.8",
    "@emotion/react": "11",
    "@emotion/styled": "11",
    "framer-motion": "6",
    "next": "12.1.5",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "17.0.25",
    "@types/react": "18.0.6",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.2",
    "eslint": "8.13.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.5",
    "typescript": "4.6.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *probably* changed the case of the drive letter on Windows in the command terminal by using a command like `cd c:\super-amazing-project` and then setup a project with a lowercase Windows drive letter. This causes strange issues like the ones you're experiencing.

### Solution 1. Change the case of the drive letter and try `yarn dev` again

You can change the *case* of the drive letter on Windows using the `cd` command like this

```
C:\super-amazing-project>cd c:\

c:\>cd super-amazing-project

c:\super-amazing-project> yarn dev
```

### Solution 2. Setup your project again using the default uppercase drive letter

Installing with the non-default lowercase drive letter on Windows may have placed your new project in a bad state. If this project is fresh, it may be easier to just run `npx create-next-app` again and copy your project files.